# Flask subsite gives 405 then 400 when submitting form

Tags: http-status-code-405

I am creating a password manager as a school project using Flask. I followed this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login guide for creating the main login and tried using the same format to add logins and retrieve them from a different table in the same database.

The sites i have are /login, /signup, /profile, /newlogin and /viewlogins. The /newlogin page will add a login f.ex facebook to the database with /viewlogins making the user able to see the different logins stored and retrieve the login information.

When accessing /newlogin the site displays and I am able to enter the data needed. When pressing submit however I recieve a 405: Method not allowed.

```py
@manager.route('/newlogin', methods=['POST'])
def newlogin_post():
    location = request.form.get('location')
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    url = request.form.get('url')
    note = request.form.get('note')
    new_login = Logins(location=location, username=username, password=password,url=url, note=note)
    db.session.add(new_login)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))
```

```py
class Logins(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    url = db.Column(db.String(255))
    note = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

This code is copied and pasted (with small modifications to accommodate different input) from the Digitalocean walkthrough that worked for /signup and /login

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
    <h3 class="title">Add a login</h3>
    <div class="box">
        <form method="POST" action="/newlogin">
            <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Location</label>
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Login location">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Username</label>
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username input">
                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Password</label>
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password input">
                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
            <label class="label">URL</label>
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Web address">
                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Note</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea class="textarea" name="note" placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Add login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
<form method="POST" action="/newlogin">
```

Any idea of how to make the code work properly? Do not worry about the security aspect of this as i just need a proof of concept.

UPDATE:
missed the

```py
    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .manager import manager as manager_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(manager_blueprint)
```

in the '**init**.py' file
it's working now

Comment: I couldn't replicate the error, I copy pasted everything except; UserMixin in class Logins, url_for(main.profile). Can you include the code for the route/function 'main.profile'

Comment: None of the tags you assigned to your questions are relevant as this is a http error code indicating your webserver does not allow the specific http request method type (get / post / head / put / delete) that your site uses on a given url.